# What is Android and why did they create a new VM?

Tags: android

> Android's embedded OS relies on the
>   Linux kernel for core system services
>   but is not embedded Linux and thus
>   standard utility libraries like for
>   example GNU C are not supported. The
>   Java framework is used to write
>   Android applications but Android is
>   not Java. Standard Java libraries such
>   as Swing are not supported.Android has
>   a Virtual Machine known as Dalvik, so
>   when the Java class files are
>   generated, this are translated to
>   Dalvik Executable files known as .dex
>   files. From this point this files are
>   not treated as java bytecode but as
>   .dex files.

So I have three questions:

1. Now I know what Android is not,
   so, what is Android?
2. What are
   core system services?
3. Why did they choose `.dex` files
   upon Java bytecode? I mean why did
   they took the work to translate or
   combine `.class` files to `.dex` files?

Comment: You should actually visit the Android SDK website: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Comment: [“What Is Android?”](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) explains this.

Comment: this is more a question for http://android.stackexchange.com/   stackoverflow is for programming related questions.

Comment: @schwiz I see no reason why this question would be off-topic here. it was just not formatted properly which it is now.

Answer (score 5):

The [*What is Android?*](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) article on the developer site describes best what Android is.

> Why did they choose .dex files upon
>   java bytecode? i mean why did they
>   took the work to translate or combine
>   .class files to .dex files?

That is because they needed a more efficient virtual machine. Their virtual machine called DalvikVM was optimized for low memory requirements.

You can read more about the [DalvikVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) in this Wikipedia entry. Make sure to checkout the external links section on that page.